# Is "barista bar" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

I am editing something that mentions a "barista bar." Is this redundant? Is it like saying a "bartender bar"? If I'm not mistaken, a barista is the Italian word for a male or female bartender, and refers more casually to servers at a coffee bar. So it doesn't make sense to me to use it with "bar" or even "coffee bar" or "cafe." Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it about a bar for baristas or is it a bar run by baristas?

Comment: No, it's about an employee cafe at a large corporation where employees can get lattes, espressos, and many different coffee drinks made by baristas.

Comment: Does the bar only serve coffee-based drinks?

Comment: The bar serves coffee and tea drinks. But no food and no other kinds of drinks. The variety of drinks is extensive.

Comment: A barista is a person who works at a coffee bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would agree that the term "barista bar" seems redundant, I could see a situation in which it may be used.  For instance, the place may also has a salad bar where employees tend to eat, and to which they refer often.  In that situation, it may be useful to specify that the bar you are talking about is not the one with the salad, but rather the one with the baristas. 
 Additionally, when deciding where to meet, some might find the phrasing "would you like to meet at the salad bar or the bar?" a bit awkward, and may say "salad bar or barista bar" instead.  If this happens often enough, the term may find its way into general use around the workplace.

Answer (score 5):

*Barista bar* is not very common. [Googling it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="barista+bar"&safe=off) mostly seems to return proper names (bars with barista in the name).

When I read *barista bar* without any context I'd think it's a bit odd and could have two meanings: a bar for baristas or a coffee bar (because I'd associate barista with coffee). In the first case it seems fine (although a bar for baristas is less ambiguous) while in the second case there are better alternatives.

Since you mean the latter, I'd go with coffee bar, hot beverage bar or just bar. The first implies the bar specialises in serving coffee and perhaps other hot beverages avoiding any ambiguity. The latter is more general and might be associated with bars serving alcoholic beverages.

Comment: Why would one bother to google this? Would you say a restaurateur restaurant?

Comment: @Lambie to see if it might be a common phrase. A *cop bar* or a *menu bar* are often used, but not everyone will have heard about those terms.

Comment: @Lambie Because googling is easy and provides information.

Answer (score 5):

Only saying "bar" would be ambiguous.

In Italy, a "bar" is more like a coffee shop–think of *Starbucks*–than a British "pub" whereas, in the US, bars normally serve alcohol.

- *The 10 Most Popular Drinks to Order at a Bar* ([Esquire](https://www.esquire.com/food-drink/drinks/g215/popular-bar-drinks-0609/))
- *16 Classic Drinks to Order at a Bar* ([Town&Country](https://www.townandcountrymag.com/leisure/drinks/g13092298/popular-bar-drinks-to-order/))
- *The Hanky Panky is a real classic, invented by the legendary Ada Coleman at the Savoy's American Bar.* ([Drinks International](http://drinksint.com/news/fullstory.php/aid/7543/The_World_92s_Best-Selling_Classic_Cocktails_2018.html))

You do not go to a barista to get coffee, a ***[barista](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/barista)*** is someone who makes and serves coffee and any other drink available on the menu. Despite being relatively recent, this Italian loanword is used all the time.

A  "barista bar" would, therefore, suggest a bar which specializes in serving hot and non-alcoholic beverages often accompanied with light meals or snacks.

Although perfectly comprehensible, the expression “barista bar” is essentially inappropriate. The word the OP is looking for is to be found among the following:  “**[cafeteria](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cafeteria)**”, “**[coffee shop](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coffee_shop)**”, “**[coffee bar](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coffee_bar)**” or in the UK, a **[cafe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cafe)** (also café).